# Can't seem to create a reverse animation to close the menu

Tags: css-animations, bulma, alpine.js

I'm sure there are many people on this forum who will tell me off for making life difficult for myself by not simply using Tailwind.CSS when making anything with Alpine.JS, but the purpose of this exercise is to show that Alpine can be done with anything, and isn't restricted to one CSS framework only.

My example uses Bulma, I prefer this as I find it to be more developer-friendly than Bootstrap or Tailwind. What I've created is a personalised navigation menu and got it to slide in perfectly from the right on the click of the button, but I can't seem to create a reverse animation to close the menu. Not that I expect many users to see this animation, but it's purely for aesthetic purposes.

My "mess of a code" is below:

HTML & Alpine

```
<body x-data="{ isOpen: false }" x-cloak directive.>

    <div x-show="isOpen" >
        <div id="side_navbar" x-transition:enter="slide_In">

            <img id="close_icon" x-transition:enter="slide_Out" class="is-pulled-right m-4" src="close_icon.svg" width="32px" @click=" isOpen = false ">

            <ul class="side_navbar-items mx-2 my-6 pt-1">
                <li><a class="side_navbar-item mb-4">link</a></li>
                <li><a class="side_navbar-item mb-4">link</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- side_navbar -->
    </div><!-- x-show component isOpen -->

<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <!-- navbar items, navbar burger... -->
    <a class="navbar-item" href="#">
      <img src="Grouplogo.svg">
    </a>

    <a role="button" class="site-menu " width="32px" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample" @click=" isOpen = !isOpen">
    <img src="burger_icon.svg">
  </a>

  </div><!-- navbar-brand -->

 <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">

  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <!-- navbar start, navbar end -->
    <div class="navbar-end">

        <div class="navbar-item has-text-weight-medium ">
        <a class="navbar-item">link</a>
        <a class="navbar-item">link</a>
       
    </div><!-- navbar-end -->

    </div><!-- x-show component isOpen -->
```

Custom CSS

```
#side_navbar{
    background-color: #57219C;
    color: #fffeff;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 20em;
    min-height: 100%;
    animation-name: slide_In;
    animation-duration: 0.1s;
}

@keyframes slide_In {
  from {
    margin-right: -200px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    margin-right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


@keyframes slide_Out {
  from {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  to {
    margin-right: 200px;
  }
}
```

Feedback is always welcome

Comment: 1) SO is not a forum. 2) My web dev company of 20 years has never used any CSS or HTML framework and you've probably visited some of our sites more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are toggling between two states, consider using `transition` and having classes corresponding to each state. Furthermore, we'd need `x-show` on the same element as the `x-transition` directives so that Alpine is aware that it needs to show/hide with a transition.

```css
#side_navbar {
  background-color: #57219C;
  color: #fffeff;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 20em;
  min-height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.1s, transform 0.1s;
}

#side_navbar.out {
  transform: translateX(200px);
  opacity: 0;
}

#side_navbar.in {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

[x-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.3.0/alpine.js" integrity="sha512-nIwdJlD5/vHj23CbO2iHCXtsqzdTTx3e3uAmpTm4x2Y8xCIFyWu4cSIV8GaGe2UNVq86/1h9EgUZy7tn243qdA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha512-HqxHUkJM0SYcbvxUw5P60SzdOTy/QVwA1JJrvaXJv4q7lmbDZCmZaqz01UPOaQveoxfYRv1tHozWGPMcuTBuvQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<body x-data="{ isOpen: false }" x-cloak directive.>

  <div x-show="isOpen">
    <div
      id="side_navbar"
      x-show="isOpen"
      x-transition:enter-start="out"
      x-transition:enter-end="in"
      x-transition:leave-start="in"
      x-transition:leave-end="out"
    >

      <img id="close_icon" x-transition:enter="slide_Out" class="is-pulled-right m-4" src="https://picsum.photos/32/32?close_icon.svg" width="32px" @click=" isOpen = false ">

      <ul class="side_navbar-items mx-2 my-6 pt-1">
        <li><a class="side_navbar-item mb-4">link</a></li>
        <li><a class="side_navbar-item mb-4">link</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- side_navbar -->
  </div>
  <!-- x-show component isOpen -->

  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <!-- navbar items, navbar burger... -->
      <a class="navbar-item" href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?Grouplogo.svg">
      </a>

      <a role="button" class="site-menu " width="32px" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample" @click=" isOpen = !isOpen">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/32/32?burger_icon.svg">
      </a>

    </div>
    <!-- navbar-brand -->

    <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">

      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <!-- navbar start, navbar end -->
        <div class="navbar-end">

          <div class="navbar-item has-text-weight-medium ">
            <a class="navbar-item">link</a>
            <a class="navbar-item">link</a>

          </div>
          <!-- navbar-end -->

        </div>
        <!-- x-show component isOpen -->
```

Comment: I liked your answer @Wongjin, just what I was looking for, many thanks